# Standard Definition of Ramified (or Branched) Cover of Topological 3-Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, 3d, geometric-topology, covering-spaces

My work with polyhedral 3-manifolds requires me to come up with a robust definition of a ramified cover in that setting. However, I want to be sure that my definition fits into the wider scheme. Therefore **I would like a *standard* definition of a ramified (or branched) cover of a topological 3-manifold, from a book** (or if absolutely necessary a paper). [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722017/a-more-general-definition-of-branched-covering) is of course very closely related but not the same, as I would like a specific literature reference; and also I want an answer specific to topological 3-manifolds, that doesn't rely on any other structure, and which can be regarded as standard.

It is very common for topologists to talk about covers of $S^3$ branching along a link. Note also the following from [Manifold Atlas](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Lens_spaces_in_dimension_three:_a_history):

> Tietze remarked that lens spaces can also be constructed by identifying the surfaces of two solid tori (as Dyck did it) and as **branched covers of $S^3$ (with ramification points)**. This idea is attributed to W. Wirtinger, his teacher; traces of it can be found in Heegard's dissertation (1898).

The fact that the idea of branched covers of 3-manifolds traces back at least to Heegard leaves me in no doubt that there *must* be a proper definition somewhere in the literature.

The definition should allow for ramification along an embedded graph, not just a disjoint union of circles, and outside of the ramification locus the map should of course just be a topological covering map (probably of finite degree).

---

**EDIT** – It seems I was not clear enough originally. I'm looking for a definition of a ramified (or branched) covering *map*. The definition should go something like this:

> Let $N$ be a 3-manifold and $M$ be a topological space. A *ramified* (or *branched*) *cover* of $N$ is a continuous surjection $f:M\to N$ such that there is an embedded graph $\Gamma\in N$—not necessarily connected, possibly empty, not containing isolated vertices, etc. etc.—such that the restriction $f:M\setminus f^{-1}(\Gamma)\to N\setminus\Gamma$ is a standard covering map (probably of finite degree?); $f^{-1}(\Gamma)$ is homeomorphic to a graph, and locally around any point $x\in f^{-1}(\Gamma)$, $f$ has a particularly nice form (i.e. it somehow looks like sheets of a covering coming together).

So the ramified cover is primarily a *map* onto a manifold. I'm looking for a reference to a standard definition, like the above, which comes from a  book (or a paper if necessary). Sorry if my original terminology was confusing. I believe, however, that it was no more confusing than the standard ambiguous terminology of covering spaces.

---

**FINAL EDIT** – Just to clarify, I cannot assume that either space is an orbifold, nor do I think that the definition can be stated in full generality using the language of orbifold projections. Here is what may be considered a prototypical example of a ramified cover (topologically $S^3\to S^3$):
[image]
There is a Euclidean simplex—call it $\Delta$—whose dihedral angles are $\pi/4,\pi/3,\pi/2,\pi/2,\pi/2,\pi/4$. If we take the *double* of $\Delta$—that is, we take a reverse-orientation copy of it and identify their corresponding faces by isometries—we get a 'polyhedral structure' on $S^3$: call this $N$. This shown in the figure on the left in the above image (arrows/colours denote face identifications). The singular locus of $N$ is the wireframe of the simplex.

Using $\Delta$ and its reverse-orientation copy, we can build another polyhedral structure on $S^3$, which is shown on the right (arrows/letters denote face identifications): call this $M$. The singular locus of $M$ is the union of the red, blue and black edges, with the appropriate identifications. Note that $M$ is *not* and orbifold, as the angle around the central red edge is $3\pi/2$. There is then an obvious map $f:M\to N$, which just sends each simplex of $M$ to the relevant simplex of $N$, depending on the orientation. Outside of the singular locus of $M$, $f$ is a covering map of degree 6, and one can very easily describe how the ramification of $f$ looks along each singular edge. For me, this map captures the essence of a ramified cover of 3-manifolds.

If we were, as Lee Mosher has suggested, to view $M$ as an orbifold with empty singular locus and $f$ as an orbifold covering projection, then we'd have to change the angles on $N$ to: red - $\pi/3$, blue - $\pi/4$, black - $2\pi$, and grey the same. But I don't think such an orbifold structure is possible on $S^3$; for example, the vertex common to the blue and black edges now only has 2 singular edges coming out of it, with angles $2\pi/3$ and $\pi$.

Comment: I think your new example has some mistakes; I am hoping that when they are cleared up, my proposed definition will work with this example. In your picture of $M$, it is hard to figure out how many copies of your simplex are intended to fit around the central red edge in $M$. Your description seems to imply that 6 copies of that simplex should fit around the central red edge (because $6 \times \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{3\pi}{2}$).

Comment: However, when I look at the picture of $M$ and count the number of simplices around the red edge, I see $6$ simplices which do not close up to form a cycle of simplices around the red edge. In the front of the diagram there is a gap, which looks like it could be filled in exactly with $2$ more simplices, thus forming a total of $8$ simplices around the red edge (and $8 \times \frac{\pi}{4} = 2 \pi$).

Comment: You can also see this gap in the outer edges of the $M$ diagram: two dotted edges, and then one solid black edge, forming three sides of a parallelogram... and then... no fourth side of the parallelogram.

Comment: Ahh sorry—drawing easily readable cut-and-paste diagrams in 3D is much harder than in 2D! You are correct that in the picture there is a gap, but what you've missed is that the 2 boundary faces in this 'gap' are being identified in $M$. That's why all the edges bounding the 'gap' are label with the same letter.

Comment: Well, if those two boundary faces are intended to be identified in $M$, then you can simply change the $\pi/4$ angle in $N$ to a $\pi/3$ angle (and $6 \times \frac{\pi}{3} = 2 \pi$).

Comment: Sure, but what about the black edges in $M$? Locally around these, $f$ is an isometry, which means, if we take $M$ to have empty singular locus, we have to choose the angle around the black edge in $N$ to be $2\pi$... and this is where the problem arises.

Comment: If your intention is that the angle in $N$ must be $\pi/2$, then instead your simplices in $M$ will fit $4$ around a black edge. Alternatively, if your intention is that the simplices in $M$ must fit $2$ around a black edge, then instead your angle in $N$ can be $\pi$.

Comment: There is a general point here: you are not correctly matching up the "orbifold structure" on $N$ with the desired polyhedral structure on $M$.

Comment: In response to your first comment after mine: the construction of $M$ out of $N$ is fixed, so we cannot change the map $f$, so I suppose we must allow the black edges in $M$ to have angle $\pi$ in order for $f$ to be viewed as an orbifold covering.

Comment: You might enjoy reading some of the mathematical literature on 3-dimensional spherical orbifolds. The definitive results are in the early 1980's PhD thesis of Bill Dunbar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111413/discussion-between-tom-sharpe-and-lee-mosher).

Comment: @TomSharpe You should be even more explicit with what you want... You seem to have a definition in mind and for some reason don't think that typical topological def "covering except at a nowhere dense set" (you would restrict to graphs or 1-skeleton it sounds like) is good enough. Is there a something else you want out of it?

Comment: I have tried to make the requirements specific in the edits to my question. The point is that I think there should be some requirement on how the map looks locally around the ramification locus, otherwise you can probably have some really weird maps. But this is precisely why I wanted a standard definition from a book, because then all of that would have been considered. Anyway, I think this question has gone as far as it can now.

Comment: I have looked at few papers and all of them use that def, they don't add any conditions but frequently specify restrictions to show a stronger result (like only looking at links). A somewhat [modern example](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.1960), and a [somewhat less modern example](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183536038)

Comment: I can't find an actual definition in your first link, and the second example you give gives the definition in terms of simplicial maps, rather than in abstract topological terms. A simplicial definition is also given [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02187917.pdf) (see page 341 for the actual definition). I think the simplicial definition might actually be the most standard one. However, the first sentence of my linked article is instructive: "*Branched coverings (of manifolds) are extensively studied but no common
definition of this notion is accepted.*"

Comment: And now you are asking for common definition... It is implicit in theorem 1 that branched covers are not just links and there is no special definition. As far as the similicial stuff, it is because they are working in that category (again mentioned by Moishe that you typically want that). If you want a special definition that fits your setting and none of the common definitions work for you then you will have to make one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To augment the answer of @PaulPlummer, you will find "covering orbifold" defined in Thurston's book [The geometry and topology of 3-manifolds](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/PDF/Thurston-gt3m.pdf), in Chapter 13, Definition 13.2.2, on page 303. And in that definition you will find a "projection $p$" which, while no terminology is offered there, we can refer to as the "orbifold covering projection".

For example, one can deduce the following from the linked answer of @MoisheKahan:

> **Theorem:** Given two Riemann surfaces $R,S$, a holomorphic map $f : R \to S$ is a branched covering if *there exists* an orbifold structure on $S$ with discrete singular locus such that $f$ is an orbifold covering projection.

Using this concept, one can formulate a similar definition which answers your question, as follows:

> **Definition:** A map $f : M \to N$ is a ramified cover if there exists an orbifold structure on $N$ with singular locus $\Gamma$ such that $f$ is an orbifold covering projection.

Keep in mind, in this statement the domain manifold $M$ is being regarded as an orbifold *with empty singular locus*, as you will see explained on the bottom of the previous page 302.

Comment: Thank you for the specific reference. The problem is that I cannot assume in general that either space is an orbifold; and even if I assume the base space is an orbifold that doesn't guarantee that the top space will be. This is why I said in my original post "*...that doesn't rely on any other structure...*". I will add an example to my original question, and after that I probably won't make any more edits.

Comment: Perhaps you have misunderstood my answer. No, you cannot assume that either space is an orbifold. In my answer, there is no assumption that $M$ is an orbifold; the assumption is unnecessary because every manifold *is* an orbifold, with empty singular locus. Also, there is no assumption that $N$ is an orbifold. The condition is that **there exists** an orbifold structure on $N$ with such-and-such a property; there is no assumption that $N$ comes endowed with that orbifold structure a priori. This is similar to many other mathematical properties that are defined by the *existence* of something.

Comment: I've augmented my answer to show you how your linked answer of Moishe Kahan translates into the exact same language as the definition in my answer.

Comment: Another thing: if you don't want to put words like "orbifold covering projection" into the definition, your other option is simply to cut and paste the content of the definition of "orbifold covering projection". Then, of course, you are obliged to give credit to the person who invented the concept in the first place, even if you don't like his terminology.

Comment: And one last thing: Your proposed outline of a definition does already rely on another structure, namely on a graph $\Gamma$ embedded in the manifold. All one needs to complete the defintion is a little more structure, which is exactly what the definition of "orbifold covering projection" supplies.

Comment: Your comments have very much clarified your answer and I see that I did misunderstand initially. However, I'm still not convinced that your definition is broad enough, as I don't think the example I'm going to provide satisfies it; and it is in many ways a prototypical example. Sorry that this is taking a while—please be patient with me as I write up the example. Good maths takes time!

Comment: Following our discussion, I see that my example does in fact fit within this definition, so I shall accept it as a correct answer. However, I'm still slightly surprised that it works :')

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the notion of *orbifold* as mentioned by Moishe Kohan in the answer you link too. You can google for orbifold and that probably is discussed in any 3-manifold book post Thurston. A good place to look is chapter 13 of [Geometry and topology of three-manifolds](http://library.msri.org/books/gt3m/) . Another reference is Peter Scott's *The geometries of 3-manifolds*.

---

I don't really deal much  with orbifolds, but I see a potential problem (maybe it actually isn't a problem) with what you are asking for. Normally polyhedra have a geometric structure, with angles and such, and the finite groups come from this geometry. The problem is not all angles can come from finite groups. As a simple example, consider a triangle where one of the angles is 1 radian. The group you would want at that point is a dihedral group action, but rotation of plane by 1 radian will not give a finite group.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for I'm afraid, perhaps I wasn't clear enough in the original question. The definition should go something like this: Let $N$ be a 3-manifold and $M$ a topological space. A *ramified cover* is a continuous surjection $f:M\to N$, such that...

Comment: Did you look at orbifold covering in Thurston? So you want a book that talks about branched covers over graphs in three manifolds? I don't know of a book that does that and if googling around doesn't find it it probably doesn't exist. Not really sure why the question you link isn't good enough except for the book stuff... It is a covering except at the graph (in the orbifold case this could be recorded with orbifold stuff).

Comment: I can't find a the phrase 'orbifold covering' in Thurston. Besides, I know that the covering space of the ramified covering need not be an orbifold.